# Convert JSONArray to arrayList

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist

I'm trying to convert a `JSONArray` which looks like this :

```
{"output":["name":"Name3","URI":"Value3"},{"name":"Name5","URI":"Value5"},{"name":"Name4","URI":"Value4"}]}
```

Into an `arrayLis`t so for example the output of `Arr[0][0]` will be `Name3`

I have tried this solution:

```
if (outputs!= null) { 
    int len = outputs.length();
    for (int j=0;j<len;j++){ 
        list.add(outputs.get(j).toString());
    } 
} 
for (String str : list) {               
    System.out.println("Item is: " + str);              
}
```

But I get the full row : `{"name":"Name3","URI":"Value3"}`

How can I get each object of my `JSONArray`?

Comment: Iterate on the inner JSON.

Comment: @maxZoom I have seen this and it does not solve my problem but thank you anyway for pointing this out .

I can do that but i want to send the full array as an argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aazelix, your Json output seem to be missing opening array bracket.
Its correct form is listed below:

```
{"output":[{"name":"Name3","URI":"Value3"},{"name":"Name5","URI":"Value5"},{"name":"Name4","URI":"Value4"}]}
```

As for the conversion to POJO

```
List<MyObj> list = new ArrayList<>();
if (outputs!= null) { 
  int len = outputs.length();
  for (int i=0; i<len; i++) { 
    JSONObject o = (JSONObject) outputs.get(i);
    list.add(new MyObj(o.getString('name'), o.getString('URL')));
  } 
} 
System.out.println("There is " + list.size() + " objects.");


public static final class MyObj {
  final String name;
  final String url;

  public MyObj(String name, String url) {
     this.name = name;
     this.url  = url;
  }
}
```

Comment: `o.name`; `o.URL`. Really?

Comment: second poing: OP had `URI`, not `URL`

Comment: I did not compile nor run the code so it may need some improvements.

Answer (score 3):

It is not specified, which JSON parser do you use, so I suppose you can choose right now and I'll suggest using `Gson` as such.

The better solution for deserializing such a structures is creating a special class for each structure, for example:

```
public class NameURIPair {
    private String name;
    private String URI;

    // getters
}
```

Then your JSON can be deserialized into a class, which holds the resulting `List` in it:

```
public class Data {
    private List<NameURIPair> output;

    // getter
}

// ...

Data data = new Gson(stringData, Data.class);
```

Since you've requested the other way, you still can get just the parsed JSON into `JsonElement` with [`JsonParser`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html)

```
JsonElement root = new JsonParser().parse(stringData);
```

Although I won't give you the full solution not to appreciate this kind of solutions :-)